# How to check if a string contains only letters or only numbers?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a login system which includes a password strength test. A password must contain letters and numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters and be between 6 and 12 characters in length. I am being told that there is a syntax error but not where. I have only just added in the password strength test to a much larger program, and I know that the rest of the program is working perfectly and that therefore this section is the issue.

```
def Password():
global UName
global FName
global SName
global Email
print('A secure password should be between 6 and 12 letters in')
print('length, have upper and lowercase letters and have numbers.')
PWord = input('Please enter a secure password:')
if PWord.isalpha() or if PWord.isdigit():
    if len(PWord) < 6 or if len(Pword) > 12:
        if PWord.isupper() or if PWord.islower():
            print('You need upper and lowercase letters. Try again')
            Password()
        else:
            print('Password is strong')
            g = open('Database1.txt', 'a')
            g.write('\n' + UName +',')#Writes user details to database file
            g.write(FName +',')
            g.write(SName +',')
            g.write(Email +',')
            g.write(PWord +',')
            g.close()#Closes file

            h = open('Database2.txt', 'a')
            Daily = input('Enter your daily energy use target:')
            Monthly = input('Enter your monthly energy use target:')
            Yearly = input('Enter your yearly energy use target:')

            h.write('\n' + UName +',')#Writes user details to the second database file
            h.write(Daily +',')
            h.write(Monthly +',')
            h.write(Yearly +',')
            h.write('0' +',')#Other values
            h.write('0' +',')#Other values
            h.write('0' +',')#Other values
            h.write('0' +',')#Other values
            h.close()#Closes file

            main()#takes user back to menu so they can login
    else:
        print('Password is not the correct length, try again')
        Password()
else:
    print('You need letters and numbers, try again')
    Password()
```

UName, FName, SName and Email are all taken from a previous function, hence why they have been declared as global variables.

By commenting out various sections, I have determined that the line

```
if PWord.isalpha() or if PWord.isdigit():
```

is throwing up the syntax error, but I can't work out why. I have created systems like this before and can't determine the issue. If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: What's the syntax error your're getting?

Comment: Please simplify your life and just use `re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9]{6,12}$', password)`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if PWord.isalpha() or PWord.isdigit():
```

But you better have to use regex for that, as explained in others answers

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

This is why the syntax error is here 
you can put multiple conditions in the if conditions by using `and` `or` operators no need to use `if` multiple times.

You can also use regex to validate the password here -

```
import re
password = raw_input("Enter string to test: ")
if re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{6,12}', password):
    # match
else:
    # no match
```

Here's the explanation for the regex

> [A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{6,12} " gm Match a single character present in the
>   list below [A-Za-z0-9@#$%^&+=]{8,} {8,} Quantifier — Matches between 8
>   and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
>   (greedy) A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and
>   Z (index 90) (case sensitive) a-z a single character in the range
>   between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive) 0-9 a single
>   character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case
>   sensitive) @#$%^&+= matches a single character in the list @#$%^&+=
>   (case sensitive) Global pattern flags g modifier: global. All matches
>   (don't return after first match) m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and
>   $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)